# Execute code after form.show()?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there anyway to execute code after `Form.Show()`? What I am doing is a small menu that will popup after user clicks the mouse right click and if I use `Form.ShowDialog()` I can't click anywhere but on that menu and it should be that if I clicked anywhere not on the menu the menu should disappear and that can only happen on `Form.Show()`.

After `Form.Show()` I am adding info to the database that is why `Form.Show()` is the only thing that suits my situation.

Code:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms["frm_Options"] == null)
    {
        frm_Options ofrm = new frm_Options();
        ofrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        ofrm.SetBounds(MousePosition.X + 5, MousePosition.Y + 5, ofrm.Width, ofrm.Height);
        ofrm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

In the other form:

```
{
    TreeNode oTreeNode = new TreeNode("New Node");
    frm_Test ofrm = (frm_Test)Application.OpenForms["frm_Test"];
    //updateTreeView is custom event created on ther main form
    ofrm.updateTreeView(false, false, oTreeNode); 
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you're talking about `ContextMenu`, means that only **one** form can appear in single moment. That means that if you can use `Show()` non blocking call. If user clicks anywhere outside of the form, you can close it, if it was already opened before. If user clicks on the form, or on any control on it (if there is any) you can raise an event (kind of `ContextMenuFormControlClicked` that main window recieves and executes necessary action (in your case DB acess).

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't quite understands the kind of ContextMenuFormControlClicked .

Comment: @yahyakh: you have 2 cases, as much as I understood. First Form opened, and user clicked out=> Form close, nothign happens. Second user clicks *on* the form, so access to DB has to be done. In this case you can raise a custom event in order to notify to mainform about that user clicked *on* the window, so acees to DB can be done.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. Question is edited with the code.

Comment: you have to declare custom event on your **context menu form**, make **main form** subscribe to it. And at the moment of click on the **context menu form** raise that event so it will be handled in **main form**. Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx, or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/winformsdelegates09042006094826AM/winformsdelegates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread before calling form.show to do your job

Comment: can you post a reference or an example